# Scraping from a webpage creates an empty dataframe

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I have a script that I have used to scrape from a webpage with success (https://www.bmreports.com/bmrs/?q=demand/dayanddayaheaddemand). Now I need to scrape another webpage from the same domain (https://www.bmreports.com/bmrs/?q=demand/rollingsystemdemand), but here the scraper can output the header of the table but not the cell data.

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd

url='https://www.bmreports.com/bmrs/?q=demand/rollingsystemdemand'
#Create a handle, page, to handle the contents of the website
page = requests.get(url)
#Store the contents of the website under doc
doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)
#Parse data that are stored between <tr>..</tr> of HTML
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')

# Defining the header
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')
#Create empty list
col=[]
i=0
#For each row, store each first element (header) and an empty list
for t in tr_elements[0]:
    i+=1
    name=t.text_content()
    print('%d:"%s"'%(i,name))
    col.append((name,[]))


    # Defining the dataframe
#Since out first row is the header, data is stored on the second row onwards
for j in range(1,len(tr_elements)):
    #T is our j'th row
    T=tr_elements[j]

    #If row is not of size 10, the //tr data is not from our table
    if len(T)!=10:
        break

    #i is the index of our column
    i=0

    #Iterate through each element of the row
    for t in T.iterchildren():
        data=t.text_content()
        #Check if row is empty
        if i>0:
            #Convert any numerical value to integers
            try:
                data=int(data)
            except:
                pass
        #Append the data to the empty list of the i'th column
        col[i][1].append(data)
        #Increment i for the next column
        i+=1

Dict={title:column for (title,column) in col}
Data=pd.DataFrame(Dict)
```

With my limited knowledge of HTML I cannot see a difference in the way that these two should be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace everything after this line

```
url='https://www.bmreports.com/bmrs/?q=demand/rollingsystemdemand'
```

with:

```
table=pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

Output:

```
   Settlement Date Time (GMT)  Demand (MW)
0       2020-06-29   09:55:00        25497
1       2020-06-29   10:00:00        25456
2       2020-06-29   10:05:00        25427
3       2020-06-29   10:10:00        25272
4       2020-06-29   10:15:00        25420
5       2020-06-29   10:20:00        25529
6       2020-06-29   10:25:00        25553
7       2020-06-29   10:30:00        25581
8       2020-06-29   10:35:00        25625
9       2020-06-29   10:40:00        25638
10      2020-06-29   10:45:00        25597
11      2020-06-29   10:50:00        25641
```

From pandas docs on [pandas.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html#pandas-read-html):

> Read HTML tables into a list of DataFrame objects.